# Would a valid request URL ever have a '.html' extension in web2py?

Tags: python, validation, web2py

The [web2py book's "Core" chapter](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core) says:

> web2py maps GET/POST requests of the form:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/a/c/f.html/x/y/z?p=1&q=2
```

> to function f in controller "c.py" in application a,

However I would imagine that the truly valid URL would not have `.html` in it. In fact, further down on the same page we read:

> URLs are only allowed to contain alphanumeric characters, underscores, and slashes; the args may contain non-consecutive dots. Spaces are replaced by underscores before validation.

And it is clear that `.html` is not part of `args` yet it has a dot in it. Therefore the example URL contradicts the valid URL as documented further down the page.

Comment: @cdonts's answer is correct. For more details, I suggest searching [The Core](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core) chapter for occurrences of "extension".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part after the dot is used by web2py to render the proper view. Both `a/c/f.html` and `a/c/f.json` calls the same function (`f` inside the  `c.py` controller), but the former will render `views/c/f.html` while the later `views/c/f.json` (if present, otherwise it will render `views/generic.json` in localhost or raise 404 in production).

Note that the extension can be omitted, and the default will be `.html`. Also, you can set `response.view` inside your controller to change the default behavior.

So yes, a valid URL might have an extension.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Just to clarify, by default, `views/generic.json` is disabled, even on localhost. This can be changed by specifying `response.generic_patterns` (the scaffolding app happens to be coded to [allow all generic views for local requests](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/1877f497309e71918aa78e1a1288cbe3cb5392ec/applications/welcome/models/db.py#L55), but that is not the default behavior).